# Use 1.2 to show that $\beta$ is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

[image]

So I'm busy with (1.3), and I've spent a large amount of time, trying to figure out how I could use (1.2) to show linear independence. Can someone provide a hint or some guidance of what to consider?

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not rely on images: they cannot be searched, they are not accesible (users that employ screenreaders cannot process them), and they do not adapt to one's display. The site has excellent typesetting capabilities for mathematical formulas, so please use them.

Comment: Assume a linear combination is the zero vector. What would you get if you take the inner product of that combination with itself?

Comment: Suppose $c_1f_{a_1}+c_2f_{a_2}+c_3f_{a_3}=0$. Then $\langle g,c_1f_{a_1}+c_2f_{a_2}+c_3f_{a_3} \rangle = 0$ for any $h \in P_2(\mathbb R)$. What does the previous equality says when $g$ is $1f_{a_1}+0f_{a_2}+0f_{a_3}$, $0f_{a_1}+1f_{a_2}+0f_{a_3}$ or $0f_{a_1}+0f_{a_2}+1f_{a_3}$?